# No route matches in Rails for duplicate error. How to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, associations, has-many-through

So I've got this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :list_id=>#<Product id: 1, name: "a", model: "", description: "", version: "", company: "", price: nil, image_source: nil, created_at: "2012-12-02 18:43:26", updated_at: "2012-12-02 18:43:26">}
```

**Notice :list_id=>#... looks a little screwed up.** Somehow `Product` got in there.

Here is product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company, :description, :model, :name, :price, :version

  has_many :list_product_interactions
  has_many :lists, :through => :list_product_interactions

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:version]
```

Here is list.rb

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :activity, :description, :title

  has_many :list_product_interactions
  has_many :products, :through => :list_product_interactions, :order => "list_product_interactions.votes_up DESC"
```

here is list_product_interactions.rb

```
class ListProductInteraction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :list_id, :product_id, :votes_activity, :votes_down, :votes_total, :votes_up

  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :product
```

The error happens when I create a duplicate of a product (product with a name that is already taken). Here is the controller where the error happens:

products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    @product = @list.products.build(params[:product])
    if @list.save
      raise "ok"
      redirect_to list_path(@list)
    else
      @list.reload
      params[:list_id] = @list.id
      render template: "lists/show"
    end
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

How do I debug? Thanks

UPDATE: added lists_controller.rb

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @lists = List.all
  end

  def new
    @list = List.new
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new(params[:list])
    if @list.save
      redirect_to @list
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @product = @list.products.build
    nil
  end
end
```

Lists show template

```
h1
  = @list.title
br
= @list.description
hr
- @list.products.each do |product|
  - if !product.id.nil?
    = link_to product.name, list_product_path(product), class: "product_link"
    '
    = product.version
    '
    = link_to "up:", "/lists/#{@list.id}/products/#{product.id}/vote_up", :method => :put
    = product.product_up_votes(@list.id)
    '
    = link_to "down:", "/lists/#{@list.id}/products/#{product.id}/vote_down", :method => :put
    = product.product_down_votes(@list.id)

hr
h3 Add products:
= form_for([@list, @product]) do |f|
  - if @product.errors.any?
    |product errors
    = pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error")
    ul
    - @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      li
        = msg
  br
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name
  br
  = f.label :version
  = f.text_field :version
  br
  = f.submit
hr
= link_to "All lists", lists_path
```

Comment: can you provide the `"lists/show"` template please

Comment: Added the lists controller and the show template.

Answer (score 0):

**Debugging Rails with ruby-debug**

---

The debugger used by Rails, ruby-debug, comes as a gem. To install it, just run:

```
sudo gem install ruby-debug
# if you run 1.9
sudo gem install debugger
```

Then you can do something like

```
<% debugger;true %>
# or in the controller/model/lib
def somemethode
    # ... 
    debugger
    # ...
end
```

When the interpreter reaches the `debugger` statement it halts and lets you interactivly explore the current environment in the console.

**Your Problem**

---

... is probably located here:

```
    = link_to product.name, list_product_path(product), class: "product_link"
```

Thats because list_product_path most likely requires a list object and the corresponding product like so `list_product_path(@list,product)` or may be you meant `lists_products_path(product)`

Answer (score 0):

The value your the **`:list_id`** param is bugged:

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", 
  :list_id=>#<Product id: 1, name: "a", model: "", description: "", version: "", company: "", price: nil, image_source: nil, created_at: "2012-12-02 18:43:26", updated_at: "2012-12-02 18:43:26">}
```

Since this is a routing error, you should probably post your **`/config/routes.rb`** and maybe the output from **`rake routes`**.

From what I can tell, you seem to be relying on **nested resource route**, something like this:

```
#/config/routes.rb
resources :lists do
  resources :products
end
```

If thats true then **krichard** is probably right, so you should use

```
list_product_path(:id => product.id, :list_id => @list.id )
list_product_path(product,@list)     #this should also work
```

**without passing both the `product.id` and `list.id`, your request will not match your nested resource route**.